# Excel formula for calculating difference between two date columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to 10k rows with two date columns. Can excel experts please provide an excel formula to calculate time difference(looking for diff in minutes) between below two date columns.

I have tried the formula =A1-B1 but its throwing #VALUE!

column A1 = 05/30/2019 21:16:48 +00:00

column B1 = 05/30/2019 21:10:28 +00:00

Comment: Did you try the DATEDIF (https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c) function?

Comment: Do all the times end in `+00:00`?

Comment: I tried DATEDIF but the ending +00:00 is throwing it off. @BigBen yeah it always ends in +00:00

Comment: You can do a simple find/replace of `+00:00` with nothing, and then `=(A1-B1)*1440` should work. Or `=(SUBSTITUTE(A1," +00:00","")-SUBSTITUTE(B1," +00:00",""))*1440` if you can't alter the original data perhaps.

Comment: Changed `3600` to `1440` in my previous comment: 24 hrs * 60 min = 1440. I was thinking seconds in an hour. You can leave off the `*1440` if you want the result as a date/time value, not a number of minutes.

Comment: As implied by @BigBen, the problem is that your time stamps are Strings and not "real dates".  Subtracting one string from another -->0.  His method will convert them to real dates, which you can then subtract.

Comment: @BigBen It works as a charm, please submit it as an answer so I can accept it. I fixed it to multiply by 1440, but you already posted in your subsequent comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by [@Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld), your times are just Strings and not true date/time values.

If you can't alter the original data (with a find/replace to eliminate all the `+00:00`), then a simple `SUBSTITUTE` and your original subtraction should work. Also, multiply by `1440` to convert the result to minutes: 60 minutes/hour * 24 hours/day = 1440 minutes/day.

```
=(SUBSTITUTE(A1," +00:00","")-SUBSTITUTE(B1," +00:00",""))*1440
```